# Gradle: Load property file dependent on profile

Tags: gradle

I want to write a gradle build script, which works in different environments (development, live).
In each environment I have to load different property sets (target directories, databases, etc.).

Is there a gradle way to read a property file dependent on the environment or a profile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to check out the [Gradle Properties Plugin](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin).

Include plugin:

```
plugins {
  id 'net.saliman.properties' version '1.4.2'
}
```

Create property files:

```
gradle-dev.properties
```

or

```
gradle-prod.properties
```

Call gradle:

```
gradle myTask -PenvironmentName=dev
gradle myTask -PenvironmentName=prod
```

Comment: This is the solution. I just wonder, that gradle do not support it out of the box.

Comment: You should read the whole article, which is an excellent documentation of gradle's property handling.

Comment: do you have a small sample project with multi env profile? that will save a lot of time to many

Answer (score 3):

Also have a look at gradle's [equivalent](https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles) of maven's profiles.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I use spring and configured it to read properties from classpath:application.properties

In this case you can add this to gradle.build with java plugin

```
if (project.hasProperty('env')) {
    println "Target environment: $env"
    sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "src/main/environment/$env"
}
```

this for different folders based on environment

So for adding resources based on environment 'dev' you should have 'src/main/environment/dev' folder (with properties file), and invoke gradle: gradle myTask -Penv=dev