# spring properties file behaviour when value not in environment file

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-security, java-security-manager

We are running on `spring boot version 1.5.10`

```
JDK : 1.8.0.52
```

Our gradle file has the entry

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '4.2.3.RELEASE'
```

We have disabled it in our application.properites through

> management.security.enabled=false

We use `application-production.properties` to set production variables

When we run in production environment the value is not affected

Do we need to explicitly set it again in `application-production.properties`?

Comment: I assume you are enabling the production profile so that `application-production.properties` are being picked up

Comment: @DarrenForsythe yes... we set the environment as "production" and values are picked from application-production.properties. What I am trying to figure out is that whether I need to explicitly set "management.security.enabled=false" in application-production.properties or application.properties will suffice

Comment: no you don't, properties get inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many profiles and split you settings to any files.
For default start application will be gived all settings from application.properties, 
for production run with "production"-profile and wil be added to default new setttings from application-production.properties
fot test will user application-test.properties and run with test profile command.

Add to pom.xml something like this style

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>h2</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>h2</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>postgres</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>postgres</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In application.properties locate spring.profiles.active=@activeProfiles@ and run with profile

Or you can use only one setting file = one profile, see example https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674407/2662111